# Open AR Scene from Unity with Xamarin.Form app?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, xamarin, xamarin.forms, augmented-reality

I am making a Augmented Reality scene on Unity, and i would like to create the application itself on Xamarin.Form and opening this AR Unity Scene in/from Xamarin, is it possible?

The AR Scene is a project for schools, it creates something similar to a museum, but with chemistry stuff, and students can learn about chemistry in a interactive way

Making an application on unity isnt that optimal, so i was thinking on creating the application in xamarin and integrating the unity scene with the application. Like opening it with a button or something.

And expecting this process to be repeated to diferent AR Scenes, not only chemistry.

Also without needing to download both applications as separated, but as one, like if i added a button to Facebook and clicking it opens Facebook app. What i would like is (if its possible), to open the AR Scene directly inside Xamarin.

Comment: I don't think it's easier than using Unity itself, but there is an option: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityasaLibrary.html

Comment: [Opinion] Combining two different platforms is almost always much harder than picking one platform, and sticking to it. Despite the limitations of the platform. A possible exception is if you can use "browser standards" to integrate the two. Does Unity provide a way to package the AR Scene as a website? If so, it *might* be possible to bundle the website into the app, and display it via a [WebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/webview?view=net-maui-7.0).